# Scaling from S2 to S3 Data tier seems to be not possible?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to scale from S2 to S3 in the SQL Azure tab, but S3 does not seem to be available although it has been introduced. Also I have plenty of DTUs available ie around 1900. Is Scaling to S3 not possible? Do I need to export the database and then import the DB as a S3 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3 is not supported on V11 servers, you need to upgrade to V12 first and then S3 will be available.

You can upgrade to v12 by following this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-v12-upgrade/

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be you are on SQL V11. You should be able to do this post V12 upgrade.